# Outlook VSTO: Updating UI and access to Outlook objects from an asynchronous method

Tags: outlook, vsto, interop, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an asynchronous method from which I update the UI of an WPF UserControl. This WPF User Control is embedded in an ElementHost. This is the way I am able to use an WPF UserControl from a winforms app (Outlook VSTO Add-in). I use an asynchronous method because I need to perform a long task so I avoid blocking UI. I also perform some queries on Outlook objects within a method I call from within the Task. See below.

```
private async void myMethodAsync()
{
    // Show a spinner
    this.UpdateUI();

    await.Task.Run(() =>
    {
         // Long task
         
         // Below I perform some queries on Outlook objects.
         this.PerformSomeQueriesOnOutlookObjects();
    });
}
```

This is working perfectly, it does not crash nor throw any exception but as I understood you cannot do below actions from an asynchronous method:

1. You cannot update UI from an asynchronous method.
2. You cannot access Outlook objects to perform actions.

So why it is working then? I do not receive any errors.

I was said in the past that I need to go back to the main Outlook UI thread to do these things by using below code. Otherwise when Outlook Object Model (OOM) detects I am trying to perform operations on Outlook objects, it throws an exception (this is not my case).

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    // here update UI and access Outlook objects
});
```

So again, why in my case is working and I do not need to enclose my code within the Invoke and I can even updating UI from the above asynchronous method?

Could someone explain me this?

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen when you run your code under the debugger? Does it fail when you run your code outside of VS?

In the former case, it is possible that the code is actually executed in the VS process and the results are marshaled to the outlook.exe process on its main thread.

Also note that older versions of Outlook do not guard against secondary thread access.

Comment: For now I am implementing it and execute it from Visual Studio and it works perfectly, no errors. I will have to test it when executing without VS. But then if I need an asynchronous method to execute a long task and this long task is constantly accessing Outlook objects, I need to constantly change to the main thread with invoke and the code gets "dirty". Every time you need to access Outlook objects or do something you need to put it into a invoke.....

Comment: [Continuation] It is feasible when all lines of codes accessing Outlook objects are together followed in a same block and you put all them in a single invoke but imagine if you have a lot of lines of code scattered... this is a pain, imagine following: lines_of_code_accessing_Outlook_Objects lines_of_code_NOT_accessing_OO lines_of_code_accessing_OO and so on.

Comment: [Continuation] so within the asynchronous method you need to constantly switching to the main UI Outlook thread, and at the end if you do this a lot of times you lose asynchronous behavior, blocks the UI and more or less it looks like a synchronous operation rather than an asynchronous one. How do you face this situation then?

Comment: Well, it all depends on what takes the most time in your code? If it is DB/network, then your current approach with `Dispatch.Invoke` is fine. If it is Outlook itself (e.g. your process all items in a large folder), then your best bet would be Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or Redemption (any language, I am its author) - MAPI objects can be accessed from secondary threads.